# How to switch tabs in Vue using Semantic-UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, semantic-ui

## Simple Example

In [semantic-ui's tab example page](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html#/examples), they have this example on how to switch between tabs (which I've also put into this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkh3jxvg/3/)):

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
  <a class="item" data-tab="first">First</a>
  <a class="item" data-tab="second">Second</a>
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="first">
  First
</div>
<div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="second">
  Second
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.menu .item').tab();
```

And this works perfectly in a simple web page.

## Vue Example 1

However, in Vue, I have this code in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/055scc66/57/) that doesn't seem to work (with the `jquery`, `semantic.js`, and `semantic.css` resources added):

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="ui container">
    <div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
      <a 
        class="item active" 
        data-tab="hello"
        @click="switchTab()"
      >
        Hello
      </a>
      <a 
        class="item" 
        data-tab="world"
        @click="switchTab()"
      >
        World
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment active" data-tab="hello">
      <p>Greetings!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="ui bottom attached tab segment" data-tab="world">
      <p>Earth!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    switchTab() {
      $('.menu .item').tab();
      console.log('Tab was clicked!');
    },
  },
});
```

Clicking on the tabs does log to the console, but the jQuery doesn't execute.

## Vue Example 2

I thought that maybe there was a problem with using jQuery in Vue, so I tried a different approach, dynamically attaching the `active` class attribute to tab.

You can check out the code in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/055scc66/58/).

**HTML**

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="ui container">
    <div class="ui top attached tabular menu">
      <a 
        class="item" 
        data-tab="hello"
        :class="{ active: isHelloActive }"
        @click="switchTabs('hello')"
      >
        Hello
      </a>
      <a 
        class="item" 
        data-tab="world"
        :class="{ active: isWorldActive }"
        @click="switchTabs('world')"
      >
        World
      </a>
    </div>
    <div 
      class="ui bottom attached tab segment" 
      data-tab="hello"
      :class="{ active: isHelloActive }"
    >
      <p>Greetings!</p>
    </div>
    <div 
      class="ui bottom attached tab segment" 
      data-tab="world"
      :class="{ active: isWorldActive }"
    >
      <p>Earth!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      isHelloActive: true,
      isWorldActive: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    switchTabs(tab) {
      if (tab === 'hello') {
        isHelloActive = true;
        isWorldActive = false;
      } else {
        isHelloActive = false;
        isWorldActive = true;
      }

      console.log('isHelloActive: ' + isHelloActive);
      console.log('isWorldActive: ' + isWorldActive);
      console.log('===');
    },
  },
});
```

The console is appropriately logged when I click on a specific tab, but it still doesn't switch.

How can I switch tabs in Vue using Semantic UI? There are also many other Semantic modules I would like to use that use jQuery in order to function.

I was also disappointed that [semantic-ui-vue](https://semantic-ui-vue.github.io/#/) doesn't have a `Tab` module.

Comment: you are approaching this in more complex way than it is. Create an array of object of the tab names first: hello, world .. and use v-for to loop and render at the same time you can use @click event to listen which tab is clicked ... i'm at work, ping me if you get no answers and I will try to put a working example later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured out what was wrong.

1. Vue doesn't play nice with jQuery.
2. Vue doesn't play nice with a UI framework that doesn't have a solid integration with it (there's the [semantic-ui-vue](https://semantic-ui-vue.github.io/#/) library but it doesn't have all the features that the base semantic-ui has.
3. In order to reference component-level variables, you need to use `this`. Vue doesn't throw an error otherwise, so it's difficult to debug. The working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/055scc66/59/) shows a working example.

My question was answered in the [Vue forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-switch-tabs-in-vue-using-semantic-ui/29860), which, if you have Vue-specific questions, you should use them as a resource.